# Creating orthogonal axis in blender (geometric model)

Tags: modeling, axis

I'm not a blender expert, so I don't know how to do this quickly.
Is it possible to create quickly something like the following?

[image]

Regardless of the "Blend4Web" or "Blender" I'd literally like to istantiate these axis as geometric models in a scene, it doesn't seem to be a default model in blender.

What I'm trying to achieve is [image]

Not exactly, but basically a couple of these reference frames two planes in front of each, a third plane and a couple of lines, maybe showing where the intersections happen.

Update: Something like the stuff below is more close to what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a Cube and position then delete unwanted Edges in Edit mode.

In Object Mode I would press Alt+C to convert the Object to a Curve from Mesh and then in the Data Tab for Curve, Fill: Full at a Depth and Resolution that suits my needs.

Once settled, I could color the axis or texture the object by converting it BACK to a Mesh from Curve so I was back on familiar ground (Curves have different behaviors).

Comment: What about the arrows?

Comment: In Edit Mode, you could close the converted axis geometry with arrows you make from the resulting cylinders or boxes. If you're going to do it a lot, it would be a benefit to do it right once and save that file to append the model later. There are also Extra Curve Objects as an addon that might have shapes you prefer to use as arrows.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more about the color and the arrows?

Answer (score 0):

XYZ correspond to RGB so I thought you'd consider color an important part of the axis mesh.

The addon under User Preferences isn't active by default but once enabled, [Shift]+[A] Curves will reveal Arrow profiles and three or so different styles exist.

You might be better off posting a drawing and seeing if a Blender user can knock out a diagram for you! The orthographic or iso view would make it fun.

(My profile seems to have been split in half - sorry for any delay in getting back to you.)

Comment: Hello, I did post a picture which is a bit closer to what I'm trying to achieve. The thing is I'd like to have the basic geometry, which intersections point highlighted and  reference frame. So I can rotate the view by myself, render, and later add labels with some notation of formulas.